# .animate() working just one time

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation, jquery-animate

I have [this site](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/187738698/Temporary%20Files/costume-page.html) (See in Full Screen).

#### Aim:

**On click of `"#cos_next"`**:

1. The image `"#img_1"` should move to the left beyond the page , and the `"#img_2"` should come in from the right.
2. The image `"cos_next"` and `"cos_grey_back"` should get removed.
3. The image `"cos_pre"` and `"cos_grey__next"` should take their place.

---

You understand what I am trying to do.
However,

#### Problem:

After the `"img_1"` moves away and `"img_2"` comes in , but clicking the image `"cos_pre"` doesn't do anything.

---

### Reference Code:

#### code inside `<script>`:

```
$(window).load(
                $("html , a").on("mousedown mouseup", function (e) {
                     e.preventDefault();
                     $("html , a").toggleClass("change");
                }
        ));

        //Slide in three monsters 
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#cos_next').click(function () {
                $('#img_1').animate({
                    left: "-=1093px"
                }, 1000);
                $('#img_2').animate({
                    left:"-=1170px"
                }, 1000);
                $("#cos_next").fadeOut("slow").remove();
                $("#cos_grey_back").fadeOut("slow").remove();
                $("body").append("<img src='costume-previous-button.PNG' id='cos_pre' />");
                $("body").append("<img src='costume-grey-next-button.png' id='cos_grey_next' />");
            });
        });

        // Slide back in the team
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#cos_pre').click(function () {
                $("#img_2").animate({
                    left:"+=1093px"
                }, 1000);
                $("#img_1").animate({
                    left:"+=1170px"
                }, 1000);
            });
        });
```

---

#### Code inside `<style>`:

```
html, a {
            cursor:url(cursor.png) 6 3 , default;
            overflow:hidden;
        }
        .change {
            cursor:url("cursor-clicked.png") 6 3 , default;
        }
        body { 
                background: url('costume-page.png') no-repeat center center fixed;    
                background-size:cover;  /*For covering full page*/
        }
        #cos_back{
            position:absolute;
            bottom:0.45%;
            left:0.10%;
            transition:0.5s ease;
        }
        #cos_back:hover , #cos_next:hover , #cos_pre:hover {
            -webkit-transform:scale(1.10);
            -moz-transform:scale(1.10);
            -ms-transform:scale(1.10);
            -o-transform:scale(1.10);
        }
        #cos_next {
            position:absolute;
            bottom:0.45%;
            left:51.60%;
            transition:0.5s ease;
        }
        #img_1{
            position:absolute;
            left:230px;
            top:0.3%;
        }
        #img_2 {
            position:absolute;
            left:1400px;
            top:0.3%;
        }
        #cos_pre {
            position:absolute;
            bottom:0.40%;
            left:41.00%;
            transition:0.5s ease;
        }
        #cos_grey_next {
            position:absolute;
            bottom:0.45%;
            left:51.60%;
            transition:0.5s ease;
        }
        #cos_grey_back {
            position:absolute;
            bottom:0.40%;
            left:41.00%;
            transition:0.5s ease;
        }
```

---

#### main HTML file:

```
<!--Loaded from the costume button on start-menu.html . Press the back button to go back-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Angry Birds Star Wars</title>
    <script src = "JQuery.js"></script>
    <script src = "JQueryUI.js"></script>
    <style>..........</style>
    <script>..........</script>
</head>
<body>
    <img src = "costume-page-new-1.png" id="img_1" />
    <img src="costume-page-new-2.PNG" id="img_2" />
    <img src="costume-back-button.PNG" id="cos_back" onclick="window.location.href='start-menu.html';"/>
    <img src="costume-grey-back-button.png" id="cos_grey_back" />
    <img src="costume-next-button.PNG" id="cos_next" />
</body>
</html>
```

Please help.
I hope I provided all the necessary info.

Thanks.

Comment: providing jsfiddle could be helpful, no one likes to debug other website

Comment: just watching your code, i think you want: `$("#cos_next").fadeOut("slow",function(){$(this).remove()});`

Comment: @A.Wolff I know . I am sorry not to provide.Because there are a lot of images so I thought of uploading to DropBox for everyone to see , and included the code in my question.

Comment: @A.Wolff what is the difference between the two ?

Comment: Waiting for animation completed. BTW, as your element is dynamic, you have to use delegation for the button: `$(document).on('click','#cos_pre',function () {...});` and of course IDs must be unique. That's said, it's really hard to figure out what is causing your issue as your code seems to fail in not only one point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems your `#cos_pre` element is appended dynamically, so doing:

```
$('#cos_pre').click(function () {
...
```

does not work, try using [jQuery.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/), like

```
$(document).on("click", "#cos_pre", function() {
..your code here
```

And you dont need separate `(document).ready(function(){ ..` for every code, add all in single `ready()` function

Comment: But then what is the problem with the element being appended dynamically?

Comment: @GaurangTandon .click() attaches event to elements that already exist on DOM, but since your '#cos_pre' elements is attached afterwards the .click() event wont work